# Error in downloading MODIS image using R script

Tags: r, r-modis

I am trying to download MODIS images using `ModisDownload()` function of rts package in R. I used following code.

```
ModisDownload(
  x = "MOD11A2", h = c(23,24), v = c(5,6),
  dates = c('2016.01.01','2018.12.31'),
  MRTpath = 'C:/modis/bin', mosaic = TRUE,
  proj = TRUE, proj_type = "UTM", utm_zone = 41
)
```

but every time same error repeats:

> Error in .modisHTTP(x, v = version, opt = opt) : 
>     the http address does not exist! Version may be incorrect OR Server is down!

Comment: Have your registered and provided your credentials with `setNASAauth()`?

Comment: yes i successfully did this.

Comment: I am also having same issue, any solution?

Comment: @Vandka, not yet.